# Regular expression to verify an import String in java

Tags: java

I have to make a regular expression in java to recognize that the line I write in the console be the package line of a class in java.

For example this line is correct: `package mx.com.example.aplication;`

But this one is incorrect: `Package mx.   com.  example.aplication`

I have to check the whole structure, with dots and uppercases

I have this:

```
^(\bpackage)[\s]{1}[A-Za-z]
```

I can’t make that my String evaluate the end with `;`

Comment: _can’t make that my String evaluate the end with `;`_ Does `;$` not work for you?

Comment: shouldn't you allow white spaces after the semi-colon as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should work:

```
^\s*package\s*\w+\s*(?:\.\s*\w+\s*)*;\s*$
```

Note that it is valid java to have more than one whitespace between the parts of a package declarations:

```
package     java  .  util   ;
```

The regex allows this. If you don't want that for whatever reason, this regex does the trick:

```
^package \w+(\.\w+)*;$
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your regular expression is just reading the word package, a white-space and then one letter. The regex below should work with your example.
`^((?:[a-z][a-z\-\_]+))(\s+)((?:[a-z][a-z\.\d\-\_]+)\.(?:[a-z][a-z\-\_]+))(?![\w\.])\s*(;)$`
This regex code above allows the word 'package' followed by a white-space, followed by a fully qualified domain name, then a semicolon. This way it will check the whole line.

Comment: Hayes Roach, I tried with your expression and it works but if I try with a bigger line  then it doesn’t work :(

Comment: Oh ok that is weird, and what do you mean by a bigger line? I want to figure out why it is not working @SebastianRuizPerez

Comment: @SebastianRuizPerez It should work with any length. Can you post what line you used that didn't work?

Comment: I saw my mistake, my line could have the symbols _ and -    btw if my line is like this: ‘mx.com.example.whatever; another words’ I get a true but I must get false, my line must finish in ;

Comment: @SebastianRuizPerez I have edited the answer to include _ and -. It should finish it ; now. Can you test it out?